# rviz seg faults when adding camera, depth cloud or image displays

Tags: ros, rviz, camera, image-view, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When I try to add one of the three (Camera, Depth Cloud, Image) displays in rviz, it immediately seg faults.

gdb gives me the following output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcmp_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S:286
286     ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __strcmp_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S:286
#1  0x00007fff77bd309e in QMetaType::registerNormalizedType(QByteArray const&, void (*)(void*), void* (*)(void const*), void (*)(void*), void* (*)(void*, void const*), int, QFlags<QMetaType::TypeFlag>, QMetaObject const*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#2  0x00007fff773c87b7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#3  0x00007ffff7dea13a in call_init (l=<optimized out>, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffba88, env=env@entry=0x7fffffffba98) at dl-init.c:78
#4  0x00007ffff7dea223 in call_init (env=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, argc=<optimized out>, l=<optimized out>) at dl-init.c:36
#5  _dl_init (main_map=main_map@entry=0x1494d80, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffba88, env=0x7fffffffba98) at dl-init.c:126
#6  0x00007ffff7deec70 in dl_open_worker (a=a@entry=0x7fffffff9c68) at dl-open.c:577
#7  0x00007ffff7de9ff4 in _dl_catch_error (objname=objname@entry=0x7fffffff9c58, errstring=errstring@entry=0x7fffffff9c60, mallocedp=mallocedp@entry=0x7fffffff9c50, operate=operate@entry=0x7ffff7dee9a0 <dl_open_worker>, args=args@entry=0x7fffffff9c68) at dl-error.c:187
#8  0x00007ffff7dee3bb in _dl_open (file=0x1426438 "/opt/ros/indigo/lib//libcompressed_depth_image_transport.so", mode=-2147483391, caller_dlopen=<optimized out>, nsid=-2, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffba88, env=0x7fffffffba98) at dl-open.c:661
#9  0x00007fffedefb02b in dlopen_doit (a=a@entry=0x7fffffff9e80) at dlopen.c:66
#10 0x00007ffff7de9ff4 in _dl_catch_error (objname=0x633770, errstring=0x633778, mallocedp=0x633768, operate=0x7fffedefafd0 <dlopen_doit>, args=0x7fffffff9e80) at dl-error.c:187
#11 0x00007fffedefb62d in _dlerror_run (operate=operate@entry=0x7fffedefafd0 <dlopen_doit>, args=args@entry=0x7fffffff9e80) at dlerror.c:163
#12 0x00007fffedefb0c1 in __dlopen (file=<optimized out>, mode=<optimized out>) at dlopen.c:87
#13 0x00007fffeff40c33 in Poco::SharedLibraryImpl::loadImpl(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.9
#14 0x00007fffeff4114f in Poco::SharedLibrary::SharedLibrary(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.9
#15 0x00007ffff52dae9b in class_loader::class_loader_private::loadLibrary(std::string const&, class_loader::ClassLoader*) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libclass_loader.so
#16 0x00007ffff52d559c in class_loader::ClassLoader::loadLibrary() () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libclass_loader.so
#17 0x00007ffff52d57d0 in class_loader::ClassLoader::ClassLoader(std::string const&, bool) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libclass_loader.so
#18 0x00007ffff52de698 in class_loader::MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary(std::string const&) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libclass_loader.so
#19 0x00007ffff7ac5a5c in pluginlib::ClassLoader<image_transport::SubscriberPlugin>::loadLibraryForClass(std::string const&) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librviz.so
#20 0x00007ffff7acc35c in pluginlib::ClassLoader<image_transport::SubscriberPlugin>::createInstance(std::string const&) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librviz.so
#21 0x00007ffff7ac0298 in rviz::ImageDisplayBase::scanForTransportSubscriberPlugins() () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librviz.so
#22 0x00007fff95b01b31 in rviz::ImageDisplay::onInitialize() () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libdefault_plugin.so
#23 0x00007ffff7a977ef in rviz::Display::initialize(rviz::DisplayContext*) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librviz.so
#24 0x00007ffff7b48815 in rviz::VisualizationManager::addDisplay(rviz::Display*, bool) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librviz.so
#25 0x00007ffff7b48c66 in rviz::VisualizationManager::createDisplay(QString const&, QString const&, bool) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librviz.so
#26 0x00007ffff7aaad0c in rviz::DisplaysPanel::onNewDisplay() () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librviz.so
#27 0x00007ffff2e3a87a in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#28 0x00007ffff752d0d2 in QAbstractButton::clicked(bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#29 0x00007ffff72909d3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#30 0x00007ffff7291b43 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#31 0x00007ffff7291c2c in QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#32 0x00007ffff6f2e50a in QWidget::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#33 0x00007ffff6edee2c in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#34 0x00007ffff6ee55dd in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#35 0x00007ffff2e264dd in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#36 0x00007ffff6ee4d93 in QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent(QWidget*, QMouseEvent*, QWidget*, QWidget*, QWidget**, QPointer<QWidget>&, bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#37 0x00007ffff6f599cb in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#38 0x00007ffff6f59269 in QApplication::x11ProcessEvent(_XEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#39 0x00007ffff6f80b02 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#40 0x00007ffff1794e04 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#41 0x00007ffff1795048 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#42 0x00007ffff17950ec in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#43 0x00007ffff2e537be in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#44 0x00007ffff6f80bb6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#45 0x00007ffff2e250af in QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#46 0x00007ffff2e253a5 in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#47 0x00007ffff2e2ab79 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#48 0x0000000000400bc7 in main ()
```

I am running ROS indigo from the debian packages (`ros-indigo-desktop-full`) on Ubuntu 14.04. (rviz version 1.11.4)

Any suggestions?

cheers

**EDIT**

this might be related to `image_view`,
`rosrun image_view image_view` gives:

```
init done 
opengl support available 
(image_view:31483): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type '(null)' in cast to 'GtkWidget'
(image_view:31483): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: instance of invalid non-instantiatable type '(null)'
(image_view:31483): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

as reported on: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues/83 and http://answers.ros.org/question/35784/image_view-giving-glib-errors-and-not-displaying-a-window/

**EDIT 2**
Added backtrace above

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203361/rviz-seg-faults-when-adding-camera,-depth-cloud-or-image-displays/) by [ffurrer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3149/ffurrer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2015-02-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-02-18**:
I would need a backtrace from gdb (use the `bt` command after it crashes) to try and diagnose what is the issue. I'm not sure that image_view and rviz use exactly the same code base, so I'm dubious of the relationship, but it is possible. I'll try to reproduce on my machine.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-02-18**:
--Also, are you using the shadow-fixed or public deb repository?-- Nvm, you are using 1.11.4, that's in public currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on your backtrace I would say that you have some problem where the image transport plugin is compiled against Qt5 but rviz is compiled against Qt4. I believe it is related to this issue:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/696

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1